# Reconstruct image using eigenmatrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, svd

I have 10 grayscale images each of 92 by 92 pixels. I have the eigenvectors matrix in the image space of dimension 8464 by 8464. Now I have to convert the basis(the eigenvectors given) to images and plot the intensity histogram of each of the 10 images. How can I do that?
P.S: I am new to image processing in MATLAB. So pardon my ignorance, if I have asked some very obvious question here.

Comment: Read [ask] and more importantly [mcve]

Comment: The eigenvectors could represent all possible 92x92 images. So, which of them do you want to obtain? Why do you need to reconstruct 10 grayscale images if you already have them? Of what do you want to make a histogram? Grayscale values? eigenvalues?

Comment: I want to obtain histograms of the eigenvalues of the images. The question asks us to reconstruct 10 grayscale images using the eigenvectors given.